# When amp-iframe is in viewport, how to make the height of amp-iframe dynamic on amp?

Tags: javascript, iframe, amp-html

The content in amp-iframe is coming with a delay. Once the content is visibile in iframe, the size of iframe needs to be changed. For this to achieve, i am using below code :

```
window.parent.postMessage({
  sentinel: 'amp',
  type: 'embed-size',
  height: document.body.scrollHeight
}, '*');
```

.Above code is working on load. But once the iframe is in viewport and then we refresh the page, the height of iframe is not changing.

Answer (score 1):

This is the indented behavior to avoid content jumps. iframe resizing will only work on either a user-interaction or if the iframe is outside the current viewport.

You can provide a overflow button to handle the case when the iframe is not resized.